# matching query does not exist Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

thanks for your time.
i've just created a model that is linked to each user although i'm not beeing able to get objects from that model for the id or any other fields from his. I'm having trouble to when try to call each user.Parceiros.object when i try the Parceiros.objects.get(id=1) on python shell or in the project i get query does not exist. althgough if i try Parceiros.objects.filter(id=1) it gets me the object wanted.

and getting this error:parceirosview() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

views.py (i've tried both):

```
def parceirosview(request, pk):
    parc = get_object_or_404(Parceiros, id=pk)
    context = {'parc': parc}
    return render(request, 'parceiro.html', context)

    def get_queryset(self):
     return super().get_queryset().filter(parceiro__user=self.request.user)
```

models.py:

```
get_user_model = User

class Parceiros (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    endereco = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    responsavel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tel = PhoneField(max_length=12)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user, self.nome)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(Parceiros, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset
```

Comment: add your url for `parceirosview` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in urls.py-> urlpatterns:

```
path('parceiro/<int: pk>/',  views.parceirosview, name="parceirosview")
```

in views.py

```
def parceirosview(request, pk=None):
        parc = get_object_or_404(Parceiros, id=pk)
        return render(request, 'parceiro.html', {'parc': parc})
```

if you want to get the related user, in your template simply call:

```
{{ parc.user }}
```

to enable reverse call from user to get parc just define a related_name in your models foreign key field.

model -> parc :

```
user = foreign_key(User, related_name="pracs", .....)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked how do i let just the creator user to update the parceiros object?

Comment: there's more than one way to do that, e.g. if you create a form for models objects so restrict the view to only the creator,. another way is to override the save function in the Admin class of the model and check if who is updating is the author then save else do nothing, and.......